# Limit of a Sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-3)^n+10}{2^n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Find the limit of the following sequence: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-3)^n+10}{2^n-1}$

I solved it the following way, and was wondering if what I did is correct:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-3)^n+10}{2^n-1} \geq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-3)^n}{2^n-1} \geq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-3)^n}{2^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{-3}{2})^n = \lim_{n\to\infty}(-1.5)^n$.

The limit does not exist, and the sequence diverges, as $(-1.5)^n =: q^n$: $q$ < 0 (the sequence alternates), and $|q|>1$ means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}q^n = \infty$ (i.e. no limit exists).

Comment: You really should not be calculating with the lims as if they existed.  A specific error is the second $\ge$ (when $n$ is odd).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the inequalities *provided* the limits exist!

But you can use the idea in a better way.

For even $n$, you have
$$
\frac{(-3)^n+10}{2^n-1}=\frac{3^n+10}{2^n-1}\ge\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\!n}
$$
so the only possibility for the limit would be $\infty$.

On the other hand, for odd $n$, $n\ge 3$, we have
$$
\frac{(-3)^n+10}{2^n-1}=\frac{-3^n+10}{2^n-1}<0
$$
so the limit can't be $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $a_{2n} \to +\infty, a_{2n+1} \to -\infty \to \text{ no limit exists}$